Can not create shortcut of file using google drive api
Here is sample code that i am trying to run.
import requests

api_endpoint = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?supportsAllDrives=true'

headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'
}

json={"name": "a.jpg", "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.shortcut", "parents": [{"id": "folder_id"}], "shortcutDetails": {"targetId": "target_file_id"}}

res = requests.post(api_endpoint, headers=headers,  json=json)
print(res.status_code)
print(res.text)

Even this code does not pickup that name and it just create a text file that contain json data.

why not use the client library.

I just love to create things from scratch .

Modification points:

I think that in this case, the endpoint is https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files instead of https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files.
In the case of Drive API v3, the value of the property parents is required to be ["folder_id"] instead of [{"id": "folder_id"}].

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.
Modified script:
Please set your access token, the parent folder ID, and the target file ID.
import requests

access_token = "###" # Please set your access token.

api_endpoint = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?supportsAllDrives=true'

headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'
}

json = {"name": "a.jpg", "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.shortcut", "parents": ["folder_id"], "shortcutDetails": {"targetId": "target_file_id"}}

res = requests.post(api_endpoint, headers=headers,  json=json)
print(res.status_code)
print(res.text)


When I tested this modified script, I confirmed that a shortcut file of "target_file_id" was created to the folder of "folder_id".

Reference:

Method: files.create

